# Authentication for HTTP Request in Node-RED

Tags: azure, http, httprequest, node-red, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use the PUT Request in Node-RED in order to save data into my Azure Blob Storage account. The GET Request works perfectly fine but the rest just send message errors. I have found out that I need to use authentication in order to use them, and that is the whole problem.

For the PUT-Request (basically sending something to the 
storage account) I write this:

https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob and replace "myaccount" with my storage account name. But I get the following message back (in message.payload):

`ResourceNotFound`The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:9b69378d-201e-0082-6da2-eba158000000
Time:2019-04-05T11:28:35.3349540Z

My problem now is that I have no idea where to get a username and a password for  basic authentication. I can only find access keys and shared access signature (SAS) in the Azure Service, and I don't know how to integrate these into my HTTP Request link. Any help?

*********EDIT 
If I write the SAS after the link for the request, I get this message back in the payload:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>MissingRequiredHeader</Code><Message>An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.RequestId:cdaa8fbc-201e-002b-2373-ef602a000000Time:2019-04-10T07:59:21.3226304Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-blob-type</HeaderName></Error>`

In the headers:

```
{"content-length":"295","content-type":"application/xml","server":"Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0","x-ms-request-id":"cdaa8fbc-201e-002b-2373-ef602a000000","x-ms-version":"2018-03-28","x-ms-error-code":"MissingRequiredHeader","date":"Wed, 10 Apr 2019 07:59:20 GMT","connection":"close","x-node-red-request-node":"e24237e0"}
```

Comment: Try to pass the sas token like `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?sp=r&st=2019-04-02T04:09:45Z&se=2019-04-02T12:09:45Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=xxxxxxZA0g%3D&sr=b`, will it work?

Comment: Helloy @JoyWang thanks for your help. I have added the SAS Token right after, as you said. I have edited my question and added the ouput I get when doing that. It says I am missing a header. I am new to this so I am not sure what this means. Do you know how to fix this?Thanks.